# Scroll multiple divs vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a structure divided into 4 sections. In one of the sections I have 3 divs inside a parent div. I have given height to the parent div so that at a time only one inside div is visible.

Now when I scroll, I want the visible div to slide up and the next div to come to the visible position. So basically within scrolling thrice I should be able to see all 3 divs inside the parent div.

I would like an animation effect on each div. For example: when I scroll, the visible div should slide up and the next div should slide to the position simultaneously.

```
<div class="col-xs-6" id="scroll">
     <div class="left">
           <div id="div1"></div>
           <div id="div2"></div>
           <div id="div3"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/6j0c7bfo/

```
$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    alert('1')
}).on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).prev()[0] !== undefined) {
        $('#' + $(e.target)[0].id).animate({
            height: '0px',
            opacity: 0.25,
        }, 1000, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    } else {
       $('#' + $(e.target)[0].id).animate({
            height: '0px',
            opacity: 0.25,
        }, 1000, function () {
          $('div[role="scroll"]').height('100px')
          $('div[role="scroll"]').css('opacity','')
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: simply add n number of div it will automatically slide your div with animation

Answer (score 1):

Well there's plenty of handy jQuery-plugins for managing scroll events/effects. Here's one that I like:

[Superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)

They're demonstrating the plugin at their site, looks like something you can make use of. They also have a documentation if you scroll down pass all the effects.

If that plugin doesn't fit you, there's, as I mentioned, lots of them. Here's list of six: http://webdesignledger.com/tools/6-jquery-plugins-for-scrolling-effects

Let me know if you need any more help. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library should not merely include a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, but [also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).